# java.lang.NullPointerException from SQLite class while inserting database in android

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I am trying to insert a data in database to `DecisionDatabase` class. But when it comes to line `ourDatabase.insert(DB_TABLE, null, cv);`
it throws a `NullPointerException`. It doesn't open `DecisionDatabase` class log says:`Couldn't open database aySonuDecisionDB.sql`. I try to find why it doesn't open database, but coludn't find. 
here is the Main class of app.

```
public class Main extends FragmentActivity {

    EditText bakici, arabaKredisi, ogrenimKredisi, tatilKredisi, elektrik;
    EditText su, internet, aidat, kasko, digerTaksitler;
    EditText diger, maasSelo, maasHilal, digerGelirler;
    TextView toplamGelir, toplamHarcama, eldeKalan;
    Spinner yil, ay;
    LinearLayout row17, row18, row19;
    TemporaryDatabase tdb;
    AySonuDatabase aDb;
    DecisionDatabase dDb;
    MainFragment mainFragment = new MainFragment();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction();;
    private final String TAG = this.getClass().getSimpleName();
    int toplamgelir, toplamharcama = 0, eldekalan = 0;
    int bakicii, arabakredisi, ogrenimkredisi, tatilkredisi, elektrikk;
    int suu, internett, aidatt, kaskoo, digergelirler, maasselo, maashilal;
    int digertaksitler, digerr, yil2;
    String ay2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        // Widget tanımlamaları
        toplamGelir = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editTextToplamGelir);
        digerGelirler = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextDigerGelirler);
        toplamHarcama = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editTextToplamHarcama);
        diger = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextDiger);
        digerTaksitler = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextDigerTaksitler);
        kasko = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextKaskoSigorta);
        aidat = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextAidat);
        internet = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextFaturaInternet);
        su = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextFaturaSu);
        elektrik = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextFaturaElektrik);
        tatilKredisi = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextTatilKredisi);
        ogrenimKredisi = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextOgrenimKredisi);
        arabaKredisi = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextKrediAraba);
        bakici = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextBakici);
        eldeKalan = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editTextEldeKalan);
        maasSelo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextMaasSelo);
        maasHilal = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextMaasHilal);
        yil = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerYillar);
        ay = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerAylar);
        row17 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.tableRow17);
        row18 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.tableRow18);
        row19 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.tableRow19);

        // Button etki tepkileri
        Button hesapla, getir, kaydet;
        hesapla = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonHesapla);
        getir = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonGetir);
        kaydet = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonKaydet);
        kaydet.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                kaydeden();

            }
        });
        hesapla.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                hesaplayan();

            }
        });
        getir.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                int yil2 = Integer.valueOf(yil.getSelectedItem().toString());
                String ay2 = ay.getSelectedItem().toString();
                tdb.Entry(yil2, ay2);
                row17.setVisibility(1);
                row18.setVisibility(1);
                row19.setVisibility(1);
                if (mainFragment != null)
                    transaction.remove(mainFragment);
                fragment();
            }
        });
        Log.i(TAG, "mainonCreate");
    }

    // Bütçe hesaplamalarını yapan yordam
    protected void hesaplayan() {
        bakicii = Integer.valueOf(bakici.getText().toString());
        arabakredisi = Integer.valueOf(arabaKredisi.getText().toString());
        ogrenimkredisi = Integer.valueOf(ogrenimKredisi.getText().toString());
        tatilkredisi = Integer.valueOf(tatilKredisi.getText().toString());
        elektrikk = Integer.valueOf(elektrik.getText().toString());
        suu = Integer.valueOf(su.getText().toString());
        internett = Integer.valueOf(internet.getText().toString());
        aidatt = Integer.valueOf(aidat.getText().toString());
        kaskoo = Integer.valueOf(kasko.getText().toString());
        digergelirler = Integer.valueOf(digerGelirler.getText().toString());
        maasselo = Integer.valueOf(maasSelo.getText().toString());
        maashilal = Integer.valueOf(maasHilal.getText().toString());
        digertaksitler = Integer.valueOf(digerTaksitler.getText().toString());
        digerr = Integer.valueOf(diger.getText().toString());

        toplamharcama = bakicii + arabakredisi + ogrenimkredisi + tatilkredisi
                + elektrikk + suu + internett + aidatt + kaskoo
                + digertaksitler + digerr;
        toplamHarcama.setText(String.valueOf(toplamharcama));

        toplamgelir = maashilal + maasselo + digergelirler;
        toplamGelir.setText(String.valueOf(toplamgelir));

        eldekalan = toplamgelir - toplamharcama;
        eldeKalan.setText(String.valueOf(eldekalan));

        row17.setVisibility(0);
        row18.setVisibility(0);
        row19.setVisibility(0);
        Log.i(TAG, "mainHesaplayan");
    }

    // Bütçe hesaplamalarını veritabanına kaydeden yordam.
    protected void kaydeden() {
        boolean didItWork = false;
        boolean isDataInDatabase = false;
        int i;
        try {

            yil2 = Integer.valueOf(yil.getSelectedItem().toString());
            ay2 = ay.getSelectedItem().toString();
            isDataInDatabase = aDb.Entry(yil2, ay2, bakicii, arabakredisi,
                    ogrenimkredisi, tatilkredisi, elektrikk, suu, internett,
                    aidatt, kaskoo, digertaksitler, digerr, maasselo,
                    maashilal, digergelirler, toplamharcama, toplamgelir,
                    eldekalan);
            if (isDataInDatabase) {
                FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
                MyDialogFragment testDialog = new MyDialogFragment();
                testDialog.setRetainInstance(true);
                testDialog.show(fm, "MyDialogFragment");

                i = dDb.getDecisionData();
                switch (i) {
                case 0:
                    aDb.EntryWithoutDialog(yil2, ay2, bakicii, arabakredisi,
                            ogrenimkredisi, tatilkredisi, elektrikk, suu,
                            internett, aidatt, kaskoo, digertaksitler, digerr,
                            maasselo, maashilal, digergelirler, toplamharcama,
                            toplamgelir, eldekalan);
                    didItWork = true;
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
                }
            } else
                didItWork = true;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            didItWork = false;
            Log.i("Log", e.getMessage() + "Error!");
        } finally {
            if (didItWork)
                Toast.makeText(Main.this, "DBEntrySucceed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
            else
                Toast.makeText(Main.this, "NoDBEntry", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
            Log.i(TAG, "mainKaydeden");
        }
    }

    // Seçilen ay ve yılın bütçesini ekrana fragment yardımıyla yazdıran yordam.
    public void fragment() {
        try {

            transaction.add(R.id.mainLinLay, mainFragment);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.commit();
            // Log
            Log.i(TAG, "mainfragment");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            Log.i(TAG, "mainfragmentException");
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();

        aDb = new AySonuDatabase(Main.this);
        aDb.open();

        tdb = new TemporaryDatabase(Main.this);
        tdb.open();

        dDb = new DecisionDatabase(Main.this);
        dDb.open();
        Log.i(TAG, "mainonResume");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();

        tdb.close();
        aDb.close();
        dDb.close();
        Log.i(TAG, "mainonPause");
    }
```

and fragment class;

```
public class MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment{
    Context mContext=getActivity();
    boolean decision; 
    DecisionDatabase dDb=new DecisionDatabase(mContext);

    int i;
    private final String TAG =  this.getClass().getSimpleName();
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Aynı tarihli kayit var!!!");
        alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Kaydetmek istediğinizden emin misiniz?");
        dDb.open();

        //null should be your on click listener
        alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Evet", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                i=0;
                dDb.delete();
                dDb.EntryDecision(i);
                dDb.close();
                dialog.dismiss();

            }
        });
        alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Hayır", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                i=1;
                dDb.delete();
                dDb.EntryDecision(i);
                dDb.close();
                dialog.dismiss(); 
            }
        });

        Log.i(TAG, "MyDialogFragmentOnCreateDialog");
        return alertDialogBuilder.create();
    }
    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStop();
        dDb.close();

        Log.i(TAG, "MyDialogFragmentOnStop");
    }
    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStart();

        Log.i(TAG, "MyDialogFragmentOnStart");      
    }   
}
```

and DecisionDatabase class;

```
public class DecisionDatabase {

    public static final String TAG = DbHelperTemporary2.class.getSimpleName();
    public static final String DB_NAME = "aySonuDecisionDB.sql";
    private static int DB_PATH = R.string._data_data_com_bilge_aysonu_assets_;
    public static final int DB_VERSION = 1;
    public static final String DB_TABLE = "decision";

    public static final String C_ID = "_id";// Special for id
    public static final String C_DECISION = "dialogDecision";

    public static final String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE decision (_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
            + "dialogDecision integer);";

    private DbHelperTemporary2 dbHelper;
    private final Context ourContext;
    private SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase;

    public static class DbHelperTemporary2 extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        public DbHelperTemporary2(Context context) {

            super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

            Log.d(TAG, "onCreate sql: " + CREATE_TABLE);
            db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

            db.execSQL("drop table if exists " + DB_TABLE);
            Log.w(TAG, "onUpdate drop table " + DB_TABLE);
            onCreate(db);
        }

    }

    public DecisionDatabase(Context c) {
        super();
        ourContext = c;
        Log.i(TAG, "DecisionDatabaseConstructor");
    }

    public void openDatabase() throws SQLException {
        ourDatabase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DB_PATH + DB_NAME, null,
                SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    }

    public void open() throws NumberFormatException {

        try {
            dbHelper = new DbHelperTemporary2(ourContext);
            ourDatabase = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            Log.i(TAG, "DecisionDatabaseOpen");
            return;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Couldn't open database " + DB_NAME);
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {

        }
    }

    public void close() {

        dbHelper.close();
        ourDatabase.close();
    }
    public void delete (){
        if(ourDatabase!=null)
            ourDatabase.delete(DB_TABLE, null, null);
    }

    public void EntryDecision(int decision) {
        int decisionentry=decision;
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(C_DECISION, decisionentry);
        ourDatabase.insert(DB_TABLE, null, cv);
        cv.clear();
        Log.i(TAG, "DecisionDatabaseEntryDecision");
    }

    public int getDecisionData() {
        Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DB_TABLE, null, null, null, null, null,
                null);
        String[] result = new String[1];

        int i_decision = c.getColumnIndex(C_DECISION);
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            result[0] = c.getString(i_decision);
        } else
            result[0] = "2";
        c.close();
        Log.i(TAG, "DecisionDatabaseGetDecisionData");
        return Integer.parseInt(result[0]);
    }

}
```

and here is the log and Exception;

```
    06-08 11:16:37.869: I/Main(326): mainonCreate
    06-08 11:16:37.909: I/DatabaseHelper(326): AysonuDatabaseConstructor
    06-08 11:16:38.351: D/DatabaseHelper(326): onCreate sql: CREATE TABLE harcamalar (c_id integer primary key autoincrement,spinnerYillar integer,spinnerAylar TEXT,editTextBakici integer,editTextKrediAraba integer,editTextKrediOgrenim integer,editTextKrediTatil integer,editTextFaturaElektrik integer,editTextFaturaSu integer,editTextFaturaInternet integer,editTextAidat integer,editTextKaskoSigorta integer,editTextDigerTaksitler integer,editTextDiger integer,editTextMaasSelo integer,editTextMaasHilal integer,editTextDigerGelirler integer,editTextToplamHarcama integer,editTextToplamGelir integer, editTextEldeKalan integer, UNIQUE (spinnerYillar,spinnerAylar) ON CONFLICT REPLACE);
    06-08 11:16:38.369: I/DatabaseHelper(326): AysonuDatabaseOncreate
    06-08 11:16:38.399: I/DatabaseHelper(326): AysonuDatabaseOpen
    06-08 11:16:38.409: I/DbHelperTemporary(326): TemporaryDatabaseConstructor
    06-08 11:16:38.579: D/DbHelperTemporary(326): onCreate sql: CREATE TABLE ayyil (_id integer primary key autoincrement,spinnerYillar integer,spinnerAylar TEXT, dialogDecision integer);
    06-08 11:16:38.639: I/DbHelperTemporary(326): TemporaryDatabaseOpen
    06-08 11:16:38.669: I/DbHelperTemporary2(326): DecisionDatabaseConstructor
    06-08 11:16:38.929: D/DbHelperTemporary2(326): onCreate sql: CREATE TABLE decision (_id integer primary key autoincrement, dialogDecision integer);
    06-08 11:16:38.990: I/DbHelperTemporary2(326): DecisionDatabaseOpen
    06-08 11:16:38.999: I/Main(326): mainonResume
    06-08 11:17:50.229: W/KeyCharacterMap(326): No keyboard for id 0
    06-08 11:17:50.240: W/KeyCharacterMap(326): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
    06-08 11:18:42.569: I/Main(326): mainHesaplayan
    06-08 11:19:32.549: I/DatabaseHelper(326): AysonuDatabaseEntryElse
    06-08 11:19:32.639: I/Main(326): mainKaydeden
    06-08 11:19:40.059: I/DatabaseHelper(326): AysonuDatabaseEntryIf
    06-08 11:19:40.069: I/DbHelperTemporary2(326): DecisionDatabaseConstructor
    06-08 11:19:40.119: I/DbHelperTemporary2(326): DecisionDatabaseGetDecisionData
    06-08 11:19:40.169: I/Main(326): mainKaydeden
    06-08 11:19:40.190: D/DbHelperTemporary2(326): Couldn't open database aySonuDecisionDB.sql
    06-08 11:19:40.190: W/System.err(326): java.lang.NullPointerException
    06-08 11:19:40.209: W/System.err(326):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:98)
    06-08 11:19:40.209: W/System.err(326):  at com.bilge.aysonu.DecisionDatabase.open(DecisionDatabase.java:69)
    06-08 11:19:40.219: W/System.err(326):  at com.bilge.aysonu.MyDialogFragment.onCreateDialog(MyDialogFragment.java:23)
    06-08 11:19:40.239: W/System.err(326):  at android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment.getLayoutInflater(DialogFragment.java:295)
    06-08 11:19:40.239: W/System.err(326):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:911)
    06-08 11:19:40.249: W/System.err(326):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1088)
    06-08 11:19:40.269: W/System.err(326):  at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
    06-08 11:19:40.289: W/System.err(326):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1444)
    06-08 11:19:40.289: W/System.err(326):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:429)
    06-08 11:19:40.309: W/System.err(326):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
    06-08 11:19:40.309: W/System.err(326):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    06-08 11:19:40.330: W/System.err(326):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    06-08 11:19:40.330: W/System.err(326):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
    06-08 11:19:40.339: W/System.err(326):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    06-08 11:19:40.339: W/System.err(326):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
    06-08 11:19:40.360: W/System.err(326):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
    06-08 11:19:40.360: W/System.err(326):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
    06-08 11:19:40.369: W/System.err(326):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    06-08 11:19:40.383: I/MyDialogFragment(326): MyDialogFragmentOnCreateDialog
    06-08 11:19:40.839: I/MyDialogFragment(326): MyDialogFragmentOnStart
06-08 11:38:26.058: E/AndroidRuntime(326): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-08 11:38:26.058: E/AndroidRuntime(326): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-08 11:38:26.058: E/AndroidRuntime(326):  at com.bilge.aysonu.DecisionDatabase.EntryDecision(DecisionDatabase.java:94)
06-08 11:38:26.058: E/AndroidRuntime(326):  at com.bilge.aysonu.MyDialogFragment$2.onClick(MyDialogFragment.java:44)
06-08 11:38:26.058: E/AndroidRuntime(326):  at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:158)
06-08 11:38:26.058: E/AndroidRuntime(326):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-08 11:38:26.058: E/AndroidRuntime(326):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-08 11:38:26.058: E/AndroidRuntime(326):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
06-08 11:38:26.058: E/AndroidRuntime(326):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-08 11:38:26.058: E/AndroidRuntime(326):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
06-08 11:38:26.058: E/AndroidRuntime(326):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
06-08 11:38:26.058: E/AndroidRuntime(326):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
06-08 11:38:26.058: E/AndroidRuntime(326):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

thanks for your helps...

Comment: are you sure the problem is in ourdatabase.insert? please check again

Comment: Post the **full** StackTrace.

Comment: ı posted stack trace.

Comment: Are you sure that the context given as parameter to DecisionDatabase constructor isn't null?

Comment: I am not sure. there are some other database classes. They do similar things with Decision Database and they works.How will I check is it null?

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be because you are calling delete before insert inside the EntryDesicion method, and hence your table is deleted. The table is deleted so you cannot insert any data on it

Comment: I remove delete method. but still same exception.

Comment: I believe both the delete and insert are not DDL operations in this case. Meaning that he is respectively deleting and inserting records of the 'decision' table.

Comment: you are right. I just checked the docs, passing null will delete all rows.

Comment: Can the OP create a git so I can get code and all the resource files?

Comment: Sorry for all continuous replies. Can you try to reference i using MyDialogFragment.this.i?